# Sale Time in Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

What are the ways we can show live sale remaining time in emails. Is there a way we can do it in Ampscript?

Earlier I was using the code like 
`Image URL/generic_countdown/?saleHours=48&startdate=09/08/2017&starttime=10:00:00&position=4&tzone=uk`

This generates live gif images. Could you please advise how to setup this or if there is any other way to implement this in Ampscript?

Comment: Are you looking to set the parameters in your image URL prior to the send time as variables? As @MarkusSlabina states, AMPScript is a server side language meaning once the email is sent, AMPScript will be fully processed and cannot change the email.

Comment: I have used the live countdown gif images in sfmc. Are you looking at customising the font styles and custom background images on the countdown? If not then I can suggest something which is a free service and has limited customisation around font colour and bg color.

Comment: @BradSapkota, Yes I want to know how to setup the live countdown gif images in SFMC. I do not want any customization. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AMPscript is processed and output rendered at send-time this isn't possible using AMPscript.

Therefore you need to include web-content hosted on your server. This could for example be the dynamic image you mentioned. This is then loaded from the web, rather than embedded to the mail.

Explaining how to create such dynamic images is a bit out of scope however and isn't directly related to salesforce. But googling "dynamic image generator" does bring up multiple results including code samples on github.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have setup the live countdown in the past.

Basically Sendtric is a free web service which provides limited customisations like font colours, background colours and can show live countdown upto 30 days.

Here is the [**link**](http://sendtric.com/).

Once you're in the site, fill out the details and click the **GENERATE** button. It will give you an image code to put into your email.

For example:

```
<img src="http://gen.sendtric.com/image/countdown?to=1503547080&bg=000000&fg=ffffff&days=1&lang=en" style="display: block;" />
```

Please feel free to read the [FAQ's](http://sendtric.com/faq/) about this service.

The exception to this is for Desktop Outlook 2007+, which will show only a static image of the timer.  However, the static image shown for this fallback will be the accurate time at the moment the user opens the email.

It is important to read their [terms and conditions](http://sendtric.com/tos/) of use for their free service.