# How to refer Javascript cloud page in my email in content builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a Javascript file written and saved in Cloud Page. Now,I want to refer this Javascript file from Cloud page inside my email in Content Builder. The reason why I am following this approach is because content builder removes Javascript statements mentioned implicitly inside emails.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The straight answer is that you can use `<script src="your hosted url of cloud age"></script>` ...... but I would strongly discourage using JS inside an Email... can you pls elobarate what you are trying to achieve using JS.

Comment: We are trying to implement the logic of Countdown within our emails in Content Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Email marketing best practice, **using JavaScript inside email is NOT recommended** [infact not supported] which might lead to security issues. Also may mark your email as SPAM or PHISHING.

Please read more here

> https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/

But, it does NOT stop you from using Count down timer.
There are many methods listed here, chose the one which suits your requirement.

- https://litmus.com/community/learning/27-how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-your-email
- [Sale Time in Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187951/sale-time-in-emails)
- https://www.emailtimers.com/guides/exact-target-countdown-timer/