# Is it possible to implement real time execution of any content within Marketing Cloud email after the email is triggered?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

There is a scenario where I need to display Date, Hours and Minutes left for the subscriber's subscription to end. I am able to implement this using Ampscript in my email and also mail is triggered through Marketing Cloud. The only challenge is every time when the user sees the email, same time is shown as that of when the email was triggered. Is there a way to keep updating the time whenever the user sees the email?

Comment: This is basically same question as you've asked yesterday - the answer provided few examples which should fit your use case perfectly: [How to refer Javascript cloud page in my email in content builder?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322161/how-to-refer-javascript-cloud-page-in-my-email-in-content-builder)

Comment: Sorry but that isnt the case. Yesterday I was trying with Javascript but later I had to let it go. Now I am trying to achieve it through Ampscript.

Comment: The examples provided have nothing to do with Javascript. Ampscript will never work, as it is processed at sendtime, and the output will not change once the email is sent. Once the email leaves SFMC you are left with static HTML. Hence the GIF based countdown timers are your only viable solution.

Comment: And another point - your use case/question should be technology agnostic. Just describe what you need to achieve, provide information on what you have tried so far, and answers will guide you towards what technology should be applied to reach your goal.